# Virtualbox not port forwarding port 8080 but other ports are ok

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am running ubuntu 18.04 on my virtualbox and my host machine is a mac. There is a service active on port 8080 on the VM but I have port forwarded that to my host the same way that I have done it for other ports via Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding. I have confirmed that other ports are properly port forwarded as I can actually see a different webpage hosted on port 5000. (And port 22 is working as that's how I've ssh to my VM).  I am not able to see a webpage when I visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 or http://localhost:8080

My problem is that I am not sure why I'm having trouble with port 8080 where my Vue app is running at. After running the command "yarn serve", I get

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ (copied to clipboard)
[19:11:02] Server listening on localhost:8080
```

Some of the things I've checked are:

Firewall:

```
sudo uft status
Status: inactive

sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Running nmap on VM shows:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5000/tcp open  upnp
5432/tcp open  postgresql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

Running nmap on host machine shows:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5000/tcp open  upnp
5001/tcp open  commplex-link
5050/tcp open  mmcc
8000/tcp open  http-alt
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
```

If I do `curl localhost:5000` from host I get what is expected but if I do `curl localhost:8080` I get 
`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Note: doing curl on both ports 5000 and 8080 returns information as expected from Ubuntu VM.

What's my problem?

If this is off topic please redirect me. I've tried posting on stackexchange network engineering but it doesn't even have the `virtualbox` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running the project on my host and worked straight away. I also created a new vue app on the VM and was able to view the webpage from the host's browser. My guess is that the project that couldn't be seen on the host browser is also using other services running on different ports which I have not port forwarded for. Although this is just my guess.